# Controller.Request.QueryString has no key in Authorization Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm trying to write a custom Authorization Filter to check the rights of a user. I have created my Filter Class and decorated my action with my custom attribute. My problem is that when the following statement is executed :

```
var controller = (Mvc.Controllers.MyController) filterContext.Controller;
var id = Int32.Parse(controller.Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

in the method

```
IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

I get a null reference error. When I debug, I can see that the QueryString property has absolutely no key (it's a GET action, taking a "id" parameter). Do you think that when the authorization filter is executed, the query string is not yet binded to te controller ? (That the authorization filters are executed too early). But if it's the case what is the intended usage of an authorization filter ? Do you think that the proper way to do it is to use an Action Filter and to override OnActionExecuting() ?

Comment: Authorization filter is to see if the user is authorized to do a specific thing on your website/page (like certain rights for example). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx. Try using the filterContext to gain access to the Querystring. Read here also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Ahmedilyas but I'm already aware of that. I actually already have access to all the properties of my controller, no problem on that side. I'll make it appear more clearly in my question.

Comment: Are you sure id is a part of a query string and not the part of the route?

Comment: Great @WiktorZychla !! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks a lot, yes it's part of the route and it's very easily accessible through the filterContext !

Comment: However, it definitely have to be an Action Filter and not an Authorization filter, otherwise I don't have access to the "action parameters" in the filterContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer suggested in a comment and accepted by the OP is: the id is a part of the route rather than the query string.